Community Cloud - Translations for custom labels / HTML Editor for Guest Users
I have a Community Cloud for Guest Users and enabled multi-language.
I have a language selector and I put a HTML Editor component with a simple, styled text.
Is there a way to have a translated content based on URL (which is domain/s/?language=it or domain/s/?language=en_US) or whatever user chooses via language selector?
I've tried {!$Label.MyCustomLabel} and {!Label.MyCustomLabel} - but it doesn't work.
I thought about using audiences, but cannot select language in filtering criteria (works only for authenticated users)
